# Wood Dimensional Stability

Tags: design, structures, wood

[image]Between Glue Laminated and steel plate sandwiched between two wood beams, which one is more dimension-ally stable?

Comment: Do you mean which assembly is more stable? Please provide two sketches with load schedules, and tell us what is changing - temps, humidity, loads?

Comment: Glue laminated can be fabricated in longer lengths I believe

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to understand what it means by dimensional stability. Both beams highlighted are engineered. So without having more detail information, which one is more stable dimension-ally?
[image]

Comment: The way Stackexchange works, you *ask* a question, and then if you want to *add* to it, you **edit your question**.  It is **not** a traditional forum.  If you *answer your question* then that belongs here -- but this looks like an addendum to your question, which you should **add to your question by editing it**.